# Is it possible to specify timezone used to creat the output in PHP DateTime format string?

Tags: php, datetime

EDIT: Thanks for all the comments, but this is **NOT** about how to output the timezone of a `DateTime` object, but about how to **SET** the timezone used to create the output **within the format string.**

I have updated the title to make this more clear.

---

Setting the timezone of a PHP `DateTime` object to output its value accordion to this timezone is no problem.

```
$datetime = new DateTime();
echo($datetime->format('y-m-d H:i:s e')."\n");

$timezone = new DateTimeZone('Europe/Bucharest');
$datetime->setTimezone($timezone);
echo($datetime->format('y-m-d H:i:s e')."\n");

// Output
22-02-25 00:52:22 US/Pacific
22-02-25 10:52:22 Europe/Bucharest
```

However, in some occasions I cannot control/access the `DateTime` object itself, but only the uses format string. For example when working with Monolog in Symfony it is quite easy to config which format string should be used when writing entries to the log files. This can be done by changing a single line in the projects config files.

So, is it possible to specify the used timezone within the format string? For example `y-m-d H:i:s e[use CET]`? This is psydo code of course, but is something like this possible?

I found several different format options on how to output the timezone **but nothing about specifying the timezone. Is this not possible?**

Comment: `https://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.format.php` shows you you can use the `T` character. _"T - Timezone abbreviation, if known; otherwise the GMT offset. Examples: EST, MDT, +05"_

Comment: @ADyson That outputs the applied timezone, is doesn't allow you to apply a timezone.

Comment: You also seem to have used `e Timezone identifier Examples: UTC, GMT, Atlantic/Azores` already. So what's the issue exactly? Maybe I misunderstood the question?

Comment: Ok. Well the format string is, indeed, used for output (or for parsing input). Are you asking how to _set_ the timezone? You can't use the format string for that.

Comment: `in some occasions I cannot control/access the DateTime object itself`...what exactly do you mean by this? It's your source code... are you talking about using some 3rd-party library?

Comment: @ADyson With all due respect: have you read the question? 

Comment: Unlike JavaScript `Date` objects, PHP `DateTime` objects have a builtin time zone—it isn't a display option. The `format()` method can only display current instance data, time zone included. I'm afraid you'll have to find a solution for your specific Symfony + Monolog stack.

Comment: @deceze yes, but evidently I misunderstood the thrust of it

Comment: Use `T` the Timezone abbreviation for format string.

Comment: @SparKot same mistake I made... read the previous comments :-)

Comment: have you considered setting the default timezone? https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.date-default-timezone-set.php